# SQL query that combines 4 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

In my Access database I have a four different tables based on a pizza company:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What query can I write to calculate the bill for just just Howard Roark? I want the table to display a single row that shows his first name, last name, address and total cost of order. I know I have to use table aliases but as I am new to SQL there's too much going on to get my head around.

Comment: How would you do this manually, i.e. from the data provided try to work out his bill in Excel or in your head.  This is how you would do it in SQL.  I'll start you off with SELECT * FROM Customers c INNER JOIN Orders o ON o.CustomerId = c.CustomerId;

Comment: Thanks, I do find that working in Excel first can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Sum(productprice.UnitPrice) as 'Bill'
from productprice 
join OrderItems on productprice.ProductId = OrderItems.ProductId
join Orders on OrderItems.OrderId = Orders.OrderId
join Customers on Orders.CustomerId = Customers.CustomerId
Where Customers.CustomerId = 'C004'
and Customers.fname = 'Howard'
group by productprice.ProductId
```

Comment: Maybe ditch the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm getting a syntax error in the FROM clause though?

Comment: updated answer, there was one single quotes was missing in and clause.